How can I authorize and endpoint with multiple policies and use an RoleAuthorizationHandler? in c# .net 6
How can I authorize and endpoint with multiple policies and use an RoleAuthorizationHandle?
This is my setup right now. These are the policies that are defined in the ServiceCollectionExtensions:
options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManagerPolicy, policy => 
            {
                policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleAuthorization(Roles.Manager,Roles.Controller, Roles.Admin));
            });
            
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.AccountantPolicy, policy => 
            {
                policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleAuthorization(Roles.Accountant));
            });

And they work fine individually. But I have endpoints that needs to be protected by either one of those policies so I created this OrAuthorizationPolicyProvider that also works just fine and I use it like this in the controller
    [Authorize(Policy = $"{Policies.ManagerPolicy},{Policies.AccountantPolicy}",
        AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

And this is the provider
public class OrAuthorizationPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    private readonly DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider _fallbackPolicyProvider;

    public OrAuthorizationPolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options)
    {
        _fallbackPolicyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(options);
    }

    public async Task<AuthorizationPolicy?> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        if (policyName.Contains(","))
        {
            var policyNames = policyName.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var policies = await Task.WhenAll(policyNames.Select(p => _fallbackPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(p.Trim())));

            var combinedPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
            foreach (var policy in policies)
            {
                foreach (var requirement in policy.Requirements)
                {
                    combinedPolicyBuilder.AddRequirements(requirement);
                }
            }

            combinedPolicyBuilder.Combine(policies.First());  // Ensures default authentication schemes are added if not overridden
            return combinedPolicyBuilder.Build();
        }

        return await _fallbackPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync() => _fallbackPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();
    
    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetFallbackPolicyAsync() => _fallbackPolicyProvider.GetFallbackPolicyAsync();
}

The problem is that I also have an RoleAuthorizationHandler which works perfectly if an endpoint only uses one policy. But since I now need to check for either of the two policies for some endpoints, it doesnt work. This handler runs for each of the policy that is protecting the endpoint and checks the role that is in the token against the roles that was inserted into the policy requirements. It will run in the order of the polices in the AuthorizeAttribute so it will start to run for the ManagerPolicy and for this example I am an accountant so it will return Task.CompletedTask without having changed the context.Succeed(). Then it will run for the AccountantPolicy and there it will change the context.Succeed(requirement); But even if the context.succeed is called for one of the polices it will still give me 403 Bearer was forbidden.
public class RoleAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RoleAuthorization>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
            RoleAuthorization requirement)
        {
            var roleClaim = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Role);

            if (roleClaim != null)
            {
                var roles = roleClaim.Value.Split(" ");
                    
                foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                    if (requirement.Roles.Any(r => r == role))
                    {
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

Am I missing something obvious or am I trying to solve this the wrong way? I know I can just create a new policy that has all of those roles in it but there are some endpoints that only the manager can use and not the accountant. So it doesnt seem like the correct way to handle this since I have other policies as well like an employeePolicy and a controllerPolicy and there are some endpoints that only the employee can do and not the accountant and so on. Plus if there are other roles is in the future is would be pain to redecorate the endpoints with those policies but If I could just add to the string in the [Authorize] attribute it would be a lot simpler
I have tried implementing this OR multiple policy logic with the role authorization handler and like I said in the post it doesnt grant me access if one of the policies fails or does not call the context.succeed(requirement). And I expected that do work since I am not calling context.Fail() in my handler but just returning Task.CompetedTask so I figured if one of those policies called context.succeed then it would be authorized but it isnt.
